# How to write len methods for futures::Stream?

Tags: stream, rust

Here's the code I tried (used a `fold()` to implement `len()` for streams but there're some weird type errors I can't understand (`do(row: Row)` returns a `Result<(), Error>`):

```
let rows_count = rows
    .for_each(|row| parse_row(&row))
    .fold(0, |acc, a| futures::future::ok(acc + 1))
    .wait()
    .unwrap();
```

Thanks!

Comment: `do` is not the real function name, I guess

Comment: Why don't you use [`Iterator::count`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count) or do I get you wrong?

Comment: `for_each()` has no return value, did you mean `map()`?

Answer (score 3):

Per default `fold` on `Streams` returns a `Future`. If you want to block on the `Stream` and get the number of elements you need to `wait` on it.

Furthermore if any element in the Stream is an error, it will panic.

Possible blocking implementation:

```
use futures::stream::Stream;
use futures::future::{Future, ok};

trait StreamExt {
    fn len(self) -> usize;
}

impl<T: Stream> StreamExt for T {
    fn len(self) -> usize {
        self.fold(0, |a, _| ok(a + 1))
            .wait()
            .map_err(|_| ())
            .unwrap()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=72370c20fb5f756a42c1e8f496a855d8)